# Nodemcu Esp8266 can connect with Xampp database but the data is not in the database. How can i fix it?

Tags: c++, c, xampp, nodemcu

I am trying to send my sensor data to the Xampp database.I can connect the nodemcu esp8266 with my xampp server. The problem is the sensor data is not stored in the database.

can you help me fix this?

void Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase() is the part where it should send the sensor data to the database.

this is my code fireAlarm.ino

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define DHTPIN D2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN,DHTTYPE);


float humidityData;
float temperatureData;

 //Fire risk based on Angstrom Index
 String stat1 = "No Fire";
 String stat2 = "Low Risk";
 String stat3 = "Medium Risk";
 String stat4 = "High Risk";
 String stat5 = "Extremely High Risk";

 //Formula to determine the fire risk using Angstrom Index
 float valIndex = (humidityData/20) + ((27-temperatureData)/10);

boolean fire = false;

const char* ssid = "Adbhzkpli";
const char* password = "icecreamcake";

IPAddress serverIP (172,20,10,9);  

WiFiClient client;    


void setup()
{

    pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DHTPIN, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);

    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(10);

  // Connect to WiFi network
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
    server.begin();
    Serial.println("Server started");
    Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("connecting...");

    dht.begin();
 }


void loop()
{ 
  humidityData = dht.readHumidity();
  temperatureData = dht.readTemperature(); 

  Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase(); 
}



void Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase()   //CONNECTING WITH MYSQL
 {

   if (client.connect(serverIP, 80))
   {

      Serial.println("connected");
      // Make a HTTP request:
      Serial.print("GET /mdff/insertsensor1.php?humidity=");
      client.print("GET /mdff/insertsensor1.php?humidity=");     //YOUR URL
      Serial.println(humidityData);
      client.print(humidityData);

      client.print("&temperature=");
      Serial.println("&temperature=");
      client.print(temperatureData);
      Serial.println(temperatureData);

      //Angstrom Index
      if(valIndex >= 4.0)
      {
        client.print("&value=");
        Serial.println("&value=");
        client.print(valIndex);
        Serial.println(valIndex);

        client.print("&status=");
        Serial.println("&status=");
        client.print(stat1);
        Serial.println(stat1);  
      }
      else if ((valIndex >= 3.0) && (valIndex < 4.0))
      {
        client.print("&value=");
        Serial.println("&value=");
        client.print(valIndex);
        Serial.println(valIndex);

        client.print("&status=");
        Serial.println("&status=");
        client.print(stat2);
        Serial.println(stat2);
      }
      else if ((valIndex >= 2.5) && (valIndex < 3.0))
      {
        client.print("&value=");
        Serial.println("&value=");
        client.print(valIndex);
        Serial.println(valIndex);

        client.print("&status=");
        Serial.println("&status=");
        client.print(stat3);
        Serial.println(stat3);

      }
      else if ((valIndex >= 2.0) && (valIndex < 2.5))
      {
        client.print("&value=");
        Serial.println("&value=");
        client.print(valIndex);
        Serial.println(valIndex);

        client.print("&status=");
        Serial.println("&status=");
        client.print(stat4);
        Serial.println(stat4);

      }
      else if (valIndex < 2.0)
      {
        client.print("&value=");
        Serial.println("&value=");
        client.print(valIndex);
        Serial.println(valIndex);

        client.print("&status=");
        Serial.println("&status=");
        client.print(stat5);
        Serial.println(stat5);

      }

    client.print(" ");      //SPACE BEFORE HTTP/1.1
    client.print("HTTP/1.1");
    client.println();
    client.println("Host: 172.20.10.9");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } 
  else 
  {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }

 }
```

I don't think my php code is the problem because I am trying to insert data to the database manually and its working fine. I think my nodemcu code is the problem.

Can you help me with my Final Year Project please. Please help me.

Comment: firewall on PC? why do you use IP address as hostname? use `IPAddress serverIp(172, 20, 10, 9)`

Comment: my firewall on pc is on. I am already tried to off my firewall and it still not working. Did I need to change from ```char server1[] = "172.20.10.9";  ``` to ```IPAddress serverIP(172, 20, 10, 9)```?

Comment: the string hostname would go over a DNS server. if that is not set right then the connection fails on name resolving

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not really understand. what are you suggest then? I'm totally lost

Comment: Try to focus on the real problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -> create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. This will help find more people willing to try to reproduce your problem.